# Долгая работа php скрипта со множественными SQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, php-nginx

Вкратце: "1 запросом можно записать данные в 25 000 строк за 0.5 с, в цикле и 10 минут будет мало, при этом в цикле 25 000 селектов выполняются за 1.5 сек. Есть подозрения что после каждого изменения происходит ужасная операция, будь то перезапись кеша, запись лога".

**Подробно**

Столкнулся с проблемой после переезда на новый сервер.

php скрипты, там где идет запись или обновление данных в базу данных - в 4 а то в 100 раз медленнее выполняются

Новый сервер имеет скорость записи на диск 230 MB/s против 76.6 MB/s(старый)
Единичное выполнение записи в бд скрипте происходит быстрее примерно на 10%

Я подумал что дело в сборщике мусора - запустил цикл на 10 000 000 операций, в котором инкрементировалась переменная. Опять же новый сервер выполнил команду быстрее

Настройки всех конфигов были перенесены без изменений

Новый сервер отличатся удвоенным количеством ядер процессора и оперативой. Версии php-fpm mysql те же.

Что еще можно протестировать я не знаю, не понимаю даже в каком направлении дальше смотреть, ведь настройки в обоих машинах одинаковые

Чтение множественных запросов из базы данных (в цикле 25 000 обращений для теста) происходит с одинаковой скоростью на разных серверах а вот запись или обновление - с разительной

Базы данных были перенесены на новый сервер

Настройки mysql добавил- но они не помогли - вот эти

```
#Фича, которая избавляет от постоянной записи в логи сразу после добавления инфы
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
#Вырубаем буферизацию таблиц для файловой системы и говорим MySQL обращаться к файлам напрямую
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#Отключение двойной буферизации
innodb_doublewrite = 0
```

основные настройки

```
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log      = 1

[mysqldump]

quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]

key_buffer      = 16M
```

Сегодня Попробовал записать 1000 файлов с тем же текстом что я вставляю в 100 строчек базы и результат меня удивил: 1000 файлов он записывает за 0.14 секунды, а 100 строк в базу данных за 3.2 секунды, при том что одним запросом MySQL можно заполнить 25 000 строк за 0.5 с - что это за феномен пока не разобрался

тестовый код

```
for( $i=0; $i < 100; $i++ ){
    $site->mySqli->query('UPDATE `test_table` SET `test`= \''.$text.'\' WHERE `id` =  \''.$i.'\' ) ');
}
```

Comment: Конфиг mysql идентичен на старом и на новом сервере?

Comment: да идентичен сейчас скину в основу его настройки

Comment: Но я думаю они мало что дадут @ErroR

Comment: вы протестируйте запись без пхп, выполните какой нить здоровый скрипт напрямую, а то может зря сюда пхп приписали вообще

Comment: Я это тестировал - выполняется запись одинаково @teran - выполнял из консоли... - в PHP просто в тестовом файле множество перезаписей

Comment: А новый сервер железный свой или VPS/VDS у хостера? Если у хостера можно в тех. под написать могут быть проблемы у них.

Comment: А можно пример **create** для  таблиц/ы?

Comment: там 25000 строк - create сюда просто не поместится - да и к тому же во всех столбцах значения int и лишь в 1 тестовом поле значение text

Comment: А как объяснить @E_p такую вещь - одним запросом SQL может добавить текст в 25000 строк за 0.5 сек, а в цикле и 10 минут будет мало, при этом записать 1000 файлов с этим же текстом в цикле занимает 0.1 с ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверил жесткий диск командой `iostat -x 1` во время долгой записи - диск был нагружен на 96-100%

Настройки my.cnf - не работали, потому что **не в ту группу настроек вписывал**

**Решение:**

Вписать в my.cnf после записи

```
#группа настройки демона mysql 
[mysqld]
#вписать следующее
```

Рекомендации Evas из Донецка помогли цитирую:

"Ну как минимум, это innodb_buffer_pool_size должен быть больше или равен InnoDB data size, а так же
Key buffer size должен быть больше или равен всему размеру индексов, innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 
и innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT. InnoDB медленнее, чем Myisam, но надёжнее в плане восстановления после сбоя. 
Лучше уделите внимание нормальной настройке my.cnf, почитайте разные манюалы, советы людей и т.д. 
Ну а вообще, надёжнее будет нанять специалиста для этого.

P.S. SSD диск так же, существенно, ускорит всё ваше добро..."

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что вы не переподключаетесь к БД на каждом запросе(это очень долго и если вы делаете это 10000 раз вполне может получиться 10 минут).

Попробуйте генераторы что бы уменьшить количество используемой памяти.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: А разве может быть такое что при SELECT в 25 000 итераций(в запросе меняется id) не происходит переподключение к базе данных(выполняется 1.5с), а при множественных UPDATE в 25 000 итерациях( вставляется текст ) - идет постоянное переподключение?(данные из тестового скрипта)

Comment: @Mcile Значит нет переподключение. При update скорее всего происходит пересчет индекса. Можно поиграться с write ahead log https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-logging.html. Еще вариант попробовать prepared statement.

Comment: @Mcile FIY Mysql позволяет отключить проверку индексов на время записи. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: сделал настройку согласно предложенной ссылке innodb_log_buffer_size=320М innodb_log_file_size=500М   перезапустил mysql -- не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это нормально, что множественный апдейт работает гораздо быстрее, чем много одиночных.

Так как СУБД проводят оптимизации при множественных аптейтах, так как время на отправку/принятие запроса не тратится, так как при апдейте происходят подготовительные операции, и.т.п. Ещё индекс перестраивается - возможно у вас в этом основная причина тормозов (вопрос не только в том - сколько апдейтить, а на сколько индексов "попадает" ваш апдейт).

НО абсолютно трезво паковать много запросов в один, если ваше приложение может сделать 25к запросов на изменение за один http запрос. И ещё - попробуйте завернуть эти апдейты в транзакцию, и запостите результат.

Comment: Из всех моих исследований по этому поводу коллеги сходятся в одном - после каждой операции перезаписывается кеш и причем перезаписывается как то ресурсозатратно - с теми же настройками на предыдущем сервере и менее скоростными жесткими дисками такой проблемы не наблюдалось. Мы игрались с настройками mysql - но это не повлияло. Обратил внимание что в my.cnf есть скобки [] - может мы не под теми скобками добавлял конфиги? Мне админ сказал что не имеет значения в какой части документа вписывать параметры. В тестах мы использовали и mysqli и PDO+генераторы

Comment: @Mcile не понятно только, зачем вы это исследуете, это же и так оченвидно - что много одиночных апдейтов делать не стоит. Но раз уж хочется - попробуйте в транзакции это сделать: думаю с ней будет гораздо быстрее.